# How hard is APPROXIMATE-#SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, lower-bounds, counting, sat-solvers

It is well known that the problem of counting the satisfying assignments of SAT, namely the problem #SAT, is #P-complete.

It is also suspected (somewhat less widely) that even deciding SAT should take time $2^{n-o(n)}$ according to the strong exponential time hypothesis.

I was wondering if there are any hardness results for APPROXIMATE #SAT, namely counting the number of satisfying assignments up to additive errors?  In particular, are there any explicit lower bounds?

Thanks!

Comment: It is easy to randomly compute an additive $\epsilon 2^n$ approximation by sampling $O(1/\epsilon^2)$ assignments. This can be derandomized efficiently in the case of $k$-CNFs for fixed $k$ (this is known as *approximate DNF counting*).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40498/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.